# Nullability mismatch in generic type parameter between two method arguments

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core, nullable-reference-types

I've written the following extension method:

```
// using System.Collections.Generic;

internal static class TExtensions {
    internal static bool In<T>(this T val, HashSet<T> hs) => hs.Contains(val);
}
```

and am trying to consume it as follows:

```
var s = DateTime.Now.Hour < 15 ? "abcd" : null;
var hs = new HashSet<string>();
Console.WriteLine(s.In(hs));
```

The compiler gives me a warning on the last line:

> **CS8620** Argument of type 'HashSet' cannot be used for parameter 'hs' of type 'HashSet' in 'bool TExtensions.In(string? val, HashSet? hs)' due to differences in the nullability of reference types.

because the compiler is resolving the `T` type parameter as the type of `s`, or `string?`; but the hashset is not a `HashSet<T>` which would be a hashset of nullable `string` (`HashSet<string?>`), rather it is a hashset of non-nullable `string` (`HashSet<string>`).

I could resolve this by either wrapping in a null check:

```
if (s is { }) {
    var result = s.In(hs);
}
```

or explicitly typing the hashset as having nullable elements:

```
var hs = new HashSet<string?>();
```

but is there some way to use the [nullable attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-attributes#attributes-extend-type-annotations) to allow this scenario? Or is there something else I could change in the `In` extension method?

Comment: I'd say the warning is doing its job -- note that `hs.Contains(s)` has the same problem. While this "works" through the magic of extension methods, you don't want to encourage calling methods on `null` values. At best it looks like a mistake, at worst it hides an actual mistake. When you're sure it's intended, I'd write it as `s!.In(hs)`, which suppresses the warning without a check. (Also, be very wary of adding extension methods to *every* type through generics -- at least consider making your class `internal` so your additions don't bleed over to other people's assemblies.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `[AllowNull]` attribute for the first parameter of the `In` method:

```
internal static bool In<T>([AllowNull] this T val, HashSet<T> hs) => hs.Contains(val);
```

However as you described in your question the actual problem here is that the inferred generic type parameter is determined by `s`. The `In` method will be called as `In<string?>` which requires the hashset to be `HashSet<string?>`. You must tell the compiler to use `string` instead of `string?`: `s.In<string>(hs)`.

If you can constraint to non-nullable reference types you can use this:

```
internal static bool In<T>(this T? val, HashSet<T> hs) where T : class => val != null && hs.Contains(val);
```

For value types the implementation would be:

```
internal static bool In<T>(this T? val, HashSet<T> hs) where T : struct => val.HasValue && hs.Contains(val.Value);
```

Note that only the first version (with the `[AllowNull]` attribute) works if the type parameter itself is nullable.

Instead of changing the extension method you can of course just use the null-forgiving-operator to shut up the compiler: `s.In(hs!)` or `s!.In(hs)`.